# Clarks Exo hydraulic brakes can't get fluid in

Tags: brakes

my son has a Carrera Kraken which is fitted with clarks exo hydraulic brakes.
he mistakenly cracked off the bleed nipple last week causing the front brake to be pretty much non operational.

I ordered a bleed kit, taken off top reservoir, connected syringe and hose to the bleed nipple. cracked it off half a turn.

However I can't push any fluid through. its solid.

I'm stumped. 1st time doing push bike brakes. I understand the principles of the system.  Am I missing something with this type of brake system or would there be a blockage or even trapped air in the system to cause this?

Comment: Clarks do some video guides, maybe they can be of use:
http://www.clarkscyclesystems.com/the-bike-bench/how-to-videos/exo-skeletal-brake-system.html

Comment: yeah i watched the vid. but for some reason the fluid wont push through